# plotting identical sequences in R using ape

Tags: r, plot

Hello I have phylogenetic trees of deep sequencing data. The problem is that many of the sequences are identical so i wanted to have those nodes that have x number of identical sequences be represented by a circle of size x. This is easily enough done in R using the APE package. The problem is I have two groups of sequences that I want to color differently. So at node 1 for example, 30% of the identical sequences come from group 1, and 70% come from group 2. Ideally these circles at nodes would actually be pie charts that show the different representation but I cannot figure out how to calculate the vector to feed ape. any ideas?

Comment: Do you have some small reproducible data we can use (that represents your problem)? And some code that makes your current graph (again, stripped down to just what we need to reproduce your graph) so we have somewhere to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a simple example:

```
owl <- read.tree(text="owls(((Strix_aluco:4.2,Asio_otus:4.2):3.1,Athene_noctua:7.3):6.3,Tyto_alba:13.5);")
piedata <- cbind(c(10,50,75),c(90,50,25))
```

What you need is:

1) To know the coordinates of the nodes
2) To be able to plot pie charts inside an existing plot

For the first part, it so happens that `plot.phylo` keep in memory the coordinates used:

```
plot(owl)
owl.info <- get("last_plot.phylo", envir = .PlotPhyloEnv)
str(owl.info)
List of 20
 $ type           : chr "phylogram"
 $ use.edge.length: logi TRUE
 $ node.pos       : num 1
 $ show.tip.label : logi TRUE
 $ show.node.label: logi FALSE
 $ font           : num 3
 $ cex            : num 1
 $ adj            : num 0
 $ srt            : num 0
 $ no.margin      : logi FALSE
 $ label.offset   : num 0
 $ x.lim          : num [1:2] 0 17.7
 $ y.lim          : num [1:2] 1 4
 $ direction      : chr "rightwards"
 $ tip.color      : chr "black"
 $ Ntip           : int 4
 $ Nnode          : int 3
 $ edge           : int [1:6, 1:2] 5 6 7 7 6 5 6 7 1 2 ...
 $ xx             : num [1:7] 13.6 13.6 13.6 13.5 0 6.3 9.4
 $ yy             : num [1:7] 1 2 3 4 3.12 ...
```

`xx` and `yy` are the coordinates of the tips+nodes (their numbering correspond to the numbering in the `edge` element of your `phylo` object). Here our inner nodes are nodes 5 to 7.
For the second point package `plotrix` comes with an handy `floating.pie` function.

So here:

```
plot(owl)
owl.info <- get("last_plot.phylo", envir = .PlotPhyloEnv)
for(i in 1:nrow(piedata)){
    floating.pie(owl.info$xx[4+i], 
                 owl.info$yy[4+i],
                 piedata[i,],
                 col=c("red","blue"),
                 xpd=TRUE)
    }
```

[image]

Additionally if you want to vary the size of the pie charts according to a variable x:

```
x <- c(3,6,2)
plot(owl)
owl.info <- get("last_plot.phylo", envir = .PlotPhyloEnv)
for(i in 1:nrow(piedata)){
    floating.pie(owl.info$xx[4+i], 
                 owl.info$yy[4+i],
                 piedata[i,],
                 radius=x[i]/5
                 col=c("red","blue"),
                 xpd=TRUE)
    }
```

[image]